# Evaluate expression in the form $a+bi$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

So, I have to evaluate $\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{-12}$ into the form $a+bi$.
I know that $i^2 = -1$ so $i = \sqrt{-1}$
What I have done is:

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{-12}
&= \sqrt{3(-1)}\sqrt{12(-1)}\\  
&= \sqrt{3}i\sqrt{12}i\\
&= \sqrt{3}\cdot i\cdot 2\sqrt{3}\cdot i\\  
&= 3\cdot 2\cdot (i^2)\\
&= 6\,i^2\\
&= 6\cdot (-1)\\  
&=-6\end{align}$$

So, my question is if I have to have the expression in the form $a+bi$ is my answer of $-6$ still correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's correct. Just take $a = -6$ and $b = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $$-6 = -6 + 0i.$$ If in doubt, you may want to write it down.

Comment: Sorry I downvoted you by pure error, if you edit ill change it.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I thought you could reverse your downvote regardless of edits just by clicking in the down arrow. Edited, nevertheless.

Comment: What's with the second downvote? Really?

Comment: It appears that after a period of time the votes become locked, I am not an expert myself, but I have upvoted now.